# Style guideline to prevent unwanted field access

Tags: c#, properties, coding-style, field

I once saw a question here about whether it is possible to embed fields in properties so they cannot be accessed in the rest of the class, e.g.

```
public string Name
{
    private string _name;

    get { return _name; }
    set
    {
        _name = value;
        // <Important stuff that would not be executed
        //  upon direct field access>
    }
}
```

Sadly this is not possible, so i thought maybe it would help to set a style guideline that *fields may never be accessed outside of a property*. Obviously one does not want to expose every field publicly so those fields would require **private properties** like this:

```
private int _progress = 0;
private int progress
{
    get { return _progress; }
    set { _progress = value; }
}
```

If this is paired with a guideline that fields need to have an underscore as prefix one could immediately tell that something is wrong if an underscore is spotted elsewhere in the class.

So my question - or rather questions, are those:

Is this a good idea?
Does using camel-case for private properties sound reasonable?
Can anyone think of a scenario where this might prove to be problematic?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the getter and setter have no side effects, there's no point in making a private property to wrap a private field. Either use a field and be done with it, or use an auto-property. Don't write six lines of code to express one line's worth of intent; you're just making your code harder to read.

Now, if your setter did have side effects, then that's a different matter. In that case, it's fine to have a guideline that you shouldn't set the field outside the property -- but consider that the constructor may need to set the field too. (Initially setting up the object's state may require that you bypass the side effects.) There may also be other cases where you want to use the field (deep copy, load/save, etc.) but that's why "use the property" should be a guideline, not a hard-and-fast rule: you want to give it some extra thought before you bypass the property.

As far as naming conventions, obviously it's up to you, but it looks very strange to me to have a camelCased property. In all the code I've seen, properties are PascalCased even when they're private.

Comment: I prefer to initialize variables where they are declared (as opposed to the constructor), that is why in most cases i would not want to use an auto-property without any field. You are right about the casing i suppose, makes it look like a local variable in camelCase.

Comment: @H.B: I think you needlessly add complexity to your code without getting much for it, what you have should be an auto property imo.